# Join Two Tables by Full Text Search

Tags: mysql, full-text-search, left-join, inner-join

This database is only used to merge two tables one which contains locations and the other latitude and longitude values. What i want to do is join the two tables by location so that the latitude and longitude values are added to table 1.

Table 1:

```
Title:                Location:                          Latitude:       Longitude
pizza shop            london, chelsea, el13 4hr          Null            Null
Phone Shop            Manchester - Derby                 Null            Null
Computer Repair       Birmingham (b70)                   Null            Null


Table 2:

Location             Latitude:          Longitude:
London               53.6658            0.25533
birmingham           54.3665            0.89336
manchester           66.3368            0.25836
```

Table 1's location column can in some cases contain data using commas dashes or more then one location hence my choice to go with full text to match what ever first match and display there longitude and latitude values.

End Result for table 1 should be:

```
Title:                Location:                          Latitude:       Longitude
pizza shop            London                             53.6658         0.25533
Phone Shop            manchester                         66.3368         0.25836
Computer Repair       birmingham                         54.3665         0.89336
```

Thanks for your help with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may looking for this

```
    select t1.Title , SUBSTRING_INDEX(t1.Location, ' ', 1)as Location , t2.Latitude  , t2.Longitude 
   from Table1 t1
  inner join
  Table2 t2
   on  SUBSTRING_INDEX(t1.Location, ' ', 1) = t2.Location
```

OUTPUT:

```
TITLE               LOCATION       LATITUDE     LONGITUDE
pizza shop          london         53.6658      0.25533
Computer Repair     Birmingham     54.3665      0.89336
Phone Shop          Manchester     66.3368      0.25836
```

[**DEMO SQLFIDDLE HERE**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fd585/3)

with `UPDATE` statment should be like that

```
    update Table1 t1
        inner join Table2 t2
        on  SUBSTRING_INDEX(t1.Location, ' ', 1) = t2.Location 
    SET t1.Latitude = t2.Latitude ,
        t1.Longitude = t2.Longitude
```

[**DEMO SQLFIDDLE**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cb126/2)

Comment: This works thanks but how do i do an update instead of select?

Comment: Thank i have just tested this on 13,000 rows and only 8000 have matched. Some of the rows that have not matched:

Peterborough, Cambridgeshire  - (Both are listed in table 2)

Old Hall Industrial Estate, Wirral , CH62 3QX  - (Wirral is listed in table 2)

Comment: Maybe i was not clear in my question but my location data may not be always at the front for example xxx, hfhfh, birmingham, fffj so the keyword can be anywhere not just at the front. And it can consist of two or three worded keyword example west bromwich or city of london

Comment: then what is the relationship between the two tables ? you have id columns ? or something that relate the tables?

Comment: No i don't i thought the relationship would be via matching the location fields between the two tables?

Comment: If i need to create id columns i can do this if need be

Comment: i advice you to redesign your tables , and put an ids to relate the tables then it will be much easier

Comment: So if i add ids but then what query can i run to match?

Comment: if you add ids , then in the update query this `on  SUBSTRING_INDEX(t1.Location, ' ', 1) = t2.Location` will be `t1.id= t2.theid`  , they must be the same `id` and `theid` for each field.

Comment: The fiddle has wrong data, e.g. `london, chelsea, el13 4hr` has the comma removed. It won't work if you just scan for spaces, because there are different delimiters, as it is the case.

Answer (score 0):

```
select t1.title, t2.location, t2.latitude, t2.longitude
from table1 t1, table2 t2
where t1.location ilike concat('%', t2.location, '%');
```

Comment: Sorry this extremely slow on my data set.